# How can I center align button inside the dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have created a dropdown menu. Inside this menu is a button for signing in. But I am not able to center align it.

[image]

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="dropdown text-center">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Login <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <button class="btn btn-info"><div class="dropdown-item"  style="width:100px; text-align:center; left:50% margin-left:50px;">Sign In</div></button>
        <h6 class="dropdown-header">New User? <a href="#">Sign up</a></h6>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><div class="dropdown-item">ABCDE</div></a>
        <a href="#"><div class="dropdown-item">UVWXYZ</div></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `text-align:center;` to the wrapper `li`. Text align should be applied to the parent of the element you want to center. You can remove the margin and left position of the div.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown text-center">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Login <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li style="text-align:center;">
                <button class="btn btn-info"><div class="dropdown-item"  style="width:100px;">Sign In</div></button>
                <h6 class="dropdown-header">New User? <a href="#">Sign up</a></h6>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><div class="dropdown-item">ABCDE</div></a>
                <a href="#"><div class="dropdown-item">UVWXYZ</div></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Or if you only want the button to be centered you could set it to a block element and use `margin:0 auto;`. This style would need to be applied to the button not the child div as outlined by [Gerard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44613017/how-can-i-center-align-button-inside-the-dropdown-menu/44613075#44613075).

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown text-center">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Login <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <button class="btn btn-info" style="width:100px;display:block;margin:0 auto;"><div class="dropdown-item">Sign In</div></button>
                <h6 class="dropdown-header">New User? <a href="#">Sign up</a></h6>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><div class="dropdown-item">ABCDE</div></a>
                <a href="#"><div class="dropdown-item">UVWXYZ</div></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were targeting the text of the button but not the button itself. Please use the below.

```html
<div class="dropdown-item" style="width:100px; text-align:center; left:50% margin-left:50px;">
<button class="btn btn-info">Sign In</button>
</div>
```